# Is this code thread safe? (shared access to object's fields)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

Is this code thread safe?

```
class Program
{
    public class Settings
    {
        public string Val1 { get; set; }

        Settings()
        {
            // load Val1 and other props from the file using XmlSerializer
        }

        private static Settings _instance;
        private static readonly object Sync = new object();

        public static Settings Instance
        {
            get
            {
                lock (Sync)
                {
                    return _instance ?? (_instance = new Settings());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(Settings.Instance.Val1);

        var thread = new Thread(
            state =>
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(Settings.Instance.Val1);
            });
        thread.Start();

        thread.Join();
    }
```

Comment: Are you ever changing the value of `Val`?

Comment: @Jaime, no - it's initialized once

Comment: make `Val1` a constant.

Comment: @ps2goat, this is a simplified code. Actually it's loaded from the file on initialization.

Comment: we answer based on what you give us.

Comment: The only thing thread safe here is creation of the singleton instance, which I prefer to use `Lazy<T>` for (http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx#lazy). If `Val1` is mutable, you will need to protect its getter and setter appropriately. If it is not mutable, and only set upon initialization, refactor it into a `readonly` field so your intent is clear.

Comment: From your code it seems that you create the instance on one thread only, after that, all other threads just get the instance and read properties off the settings. If that is the case, you should not expose public setters to your properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, this code is not thread safe, because your are locking when the instance object is returned but the `Val1` can be changed if other threads setting variable value are there.
If this `Val1` is not changing i.e. it is set only once then your code will be thread safe as you are only accessing the values.

**EDIT** As per your edited question and comments posted your code will be thread-safe as `Val1` is initialized only in constructor and it is thread safe because of `lock (Sync)` statement

Comment: are you sure? I've heard memory reads must be synchronized too, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: if your are changing the value of `Var1` in between but as per your conversation I think is is set only once and if you have multiple reads on a variable which is set only once and that too in synchronized way then reads do not need to be synchronized as it will be returning the same value.....